# Would it work if I put grub2 boot mount on mbr hdd and the rest on gpt on non-UEFI

Tags: grub2

Would it work if I put grub2 boot mount on mbr hdd and the rest on gpt on non-UEFI

Comment: I only have a BIOS system and use gpt on SSD with / (root) and all data was on a drive that was still MBR(msdos). You can now mix MBR & gpt for data. It just is booting where you need to be consistent with UEFI/gpt and BIOS/MBR. And best that all drives are same but not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be an issue.

An installation with `/boot/` on an MBR partitioned disk is still a BIOS/MBR installation and the scripts should automatically find and configure the corresponding root filesystem, even if it is on a GPT partitioned disk.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. That saved me a lot of time and space on the ssd.